# sqlalchemy installation is failing in pycharm

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, pycharm

Whenever the installation is finished, a red signal keeps telling the module should be installed as if nothing had happened. I'm a new joiner to Flask. If I do the same thing out of the lampp directory all things look good but not in /opt/lampp/htdocs. Anyone has any idea what's the issue here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4lXD.png)

Comment: With your project open in PyCharm, open a Terminal window and run `pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy`

Comment: thanks - I solved the way as -run "yum install python-devel mysql-devel" before installing mysqlclient --> then install mysqlclient --> fine for now